# adding images to a span

Tags: javascript, html, append

i am creating a black jack game, and im trying to have the suit appear next to the card that is drawn. However the suit is only showing on the last card drawn, but i want it to be shown after every card thats drawn.

```
 const drawCard = () => {
    getCardValue() //returns value from ace-k
    getCardSuit() //return heart, spade etc. and sets the corresponding src to img
    let cardSpan = document.createElement('span');
    cardSpan.innerHTML = ` ${cardNumber} ${cardSuit} `
    cardSpan.appendChild(img)
    playerHand.append(cardSpan)
}
```

(im using helper functions to get the card number and card suit). The above code is creating a new span for every card, but like i said only the last card is appending the image. when i console.log it in dev tools i get this

```
<span>3 clubs</span>
<span>
  5 Hearts
  <img src... etc>
</span>
```

any body know how i can get it to appear next to every card? thank you.

Comment: The problem most like exists in `getCardSuit`, you could add that After the cardSpan is declared and pass it like `getCardSuit(cardSpan)` and use `cardSpan` within `getCardSuit`

Comment: We'll need to see all the relevant code (the helper functions) in a minimal executable example before we can say for sure what the issue is.

Comment: hey imvain2 you were right, the problem was in the get card suit! thank you guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you only have one image, which is already appended somewhere else, so it moves to the other span. How about:

```
const image = document.createElement('image')
image.src = ???
cardSpan.appendChild(image)
```

Comment: This is just a guess and should really be a comment. The more likely cause is a closure around a looping variable.

Comment: hey! you were right, so i originally only had a document.create(img) at the top of the page, i instead put it inside the get card suit and returned the image, created another helper functions which takes in the card number plus card suit ans viola it worked!